# Visual Studio Code - Strangely Typescript compiler (tsc) not exists

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsc

I'm getting this error pressing Ctrl+Shift+B trying to compiling a Typescript file:

(Translated)

> "tsc" is not recognized as an internal or external command...

[image: ScreenShot for the problem]

It's not supposed to be already included???

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot specify, Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Did you installed `tsc` globally?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was my solution. Still it's a little bit "out of my range".

1. Download [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48593)
2. Add the installed folder to Path example (In my case, it worked):

`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\`

PS: I don't why but I had to replace the second parameter of the "args" setting: "${workspace}" instead of "." in task.json

Answer (score 2):

Try installing tsc with `npm install -g typescript`.

Comment: Sorry, my proxy config it's a mess which doesn't allow me to do it. I'm working on a Cuban enterprise and there's some security restrictions and I understand them. So, I was quietly looking for an offline solution and then I remembered the world is not made for us while the embargo is still there.